# How protect information stored on a server that is used by a program (also on that server) that runs as a service?

Tags: security, encryption

We've developed a program that runs as a service (so it'll start up and run in the background when the server starts up). The first time it's setup, the admin sets a bunch of info (user/pass, and other info) that the program then uses to do its stuff (this info can be changed). Currently, we're just using a database to store that info but it's in cleartext.

I could encrypt it, but I'd have to have the key to decrypt stored in the program since it needs to be able to run without human intervention.

What's the best solution (if any) to this?

(Just for clarification: I want to protect it from local access)

Answer (score 0):

Local access?  Well there is this little program called [OllyDBG](http://www.ollydbg.de/) its a free debugger and you can attach it to a process and view everything in memory for a given process,  this includes a secret key.  Perhaps you should be more clear about your threat model.

Comment: You might be right, it just feels wrong to leave that stuff clear on the server, regardless of whether everything's snoopable. I'm not really concerned about a person who has physical access to the server so much as if someone hacks into the server, I'd prefer that info be encrypted and tough for them to access.

Comment: @Don Rhummy A debugger is a piece of software,  physical access is not required.  Perhaps you aren't looking for security solution but rather "(in)Security Though Obscurity".  Keep in mind hashing passwords is very different,  and this is something you should be doing.

Comment: hashing the passwords is not an option as these are passwords used by the program to "talk" to a service on another server. Hashing is one way and the program needs to work without human intervention.

Comment: @Don Rhummy So wait,  are you storing a password inside your customer's binaries to talk to your servers?  If so,  then that is a very serious vulnerability.

Comment: no, it's a pop3connector sitting on the server that needs to be able to talk to a pop3 server somewhere else. So the login info for the pop3 account is sitting on the server. I want to protect that login info somehow.

Comment: @Don Rhummy  from who?  If the machine is owned then they can send as much spam as they want,  or attach a debuger and call the mail function in your application.  Its a moot point.